# Multiple Containers Loading Java3D

Tags: java, java-3d

I am trying to make a 3D interface using Java3D for the Multiple Container Loading problem.

I want to visualize each container and items already packed in it in seperate frames. (for example , if I have 3 containers , there will be 3 different frames )

In the container's class , I added a BranchGroup variable :

```
 private static BranchGroup scene ;
```

and in the constructor, I created the BranchGroup scene and a frame (I will post the Interface class above)

```
public ContainerW(final int iD) {
        super();
        cRef = iD;
        this.emptyBreadth = 0;
        this.length = 0.8;
        this.height = 0.6;
        this.breadth = 0.5 - emptyBreadth;
        this.usedVolume = 0;
        volume = length * breadth * height;
        this.packedItems = new ArrayList<ItemsUnit>();
        scene = new BranchGroup();
        Frame frame = new MainFrame(new Interface(scene),800, 800); 

    }
```

when a new item is packed, I add this (I added the new Node to the BranchGroup scene ) :

```
  scene.addChild(Interface.addItem(item[p].getLength(), item[p].getBreadth(), item[p].getBreadth(), x, y, z));
```

( `x`, `y` and `z` are the translation parameters )

In the `Interface` class, I wrote a method to create the frame and draw the container in it and another method to add the item's 3D `Node`.

```
package Interface3D;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.media.j3d.Appearance;
import javax.media.j3d.BranchGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.Canvas3D;
import javax.media.j3d.PolygonAttributes;
import javax.media.j3d.Transform3D;
import javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup;
import javax.media.j3d.TransparencyAttributes;
import javax.vecmath.AxisAngle4d;
import javax.vecmath.Vector3f;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.Box;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.SimpleUniverse;
import Classes.ContainerW;

public class Interface extends Applet{


    public Interface(BranchGroup scene) {


         this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
           Canvas3D canvas3D = new Canvas3D(SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration());
            this.add(canvas3D, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            SimpleUniverse simpleU = new SimpleUniverse(canvas3D);
            simpleU.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

        //create an appearance for the container
        Appearance app = new Appearance();
        //Create the polygon attributes
        PolygonAttributes polyAttr = new PolygonAttributes();
        //Set them so that the draw mode is polygon line
        polyAttr.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_LINE);
        polyAttr.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
        //Use these in the appearance
        app.setPolygonAttributes(polyAttr);

        //rotate the view angle 
        Transform3D rotateCube = new Transform3D();
        rotateCube.set(new AxisAngle4d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, Math.PI /4.0));

        //create a transform Group for the container
        TransformGroup tg1 = new TransformGroup(rotateCube);
        tg1.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);

        //create a box: container
        Box container = new Box ( (float) ContainerW.getLength() , (float) ContainerW.getBreadth(), (float) ContainerW.getHeight(), app);

        //add the container to the first transform group
        tg1.addChild(container);

        //add the first transform group to the branch group
        scene.addChild(tg1);

        scene.compile();

        simpleU.addBranchGraph(scene);


    }





       /**
        * adding an item box into the container in the position (x, y, z)
        * @param x
        * @param y
        * @param z
        */
       public static TransformGroup addItem(double l, double b, double h, double x, double y, double z) {

           TransformGroup tg2 = new TransformGroup ();
           //set the appearance of the product boxes (transparent) 
           Appearance app = new Appearance(); 
           app.setTransparencyAttributes(new TransparencyAttributes(TransparencyAttributes.BLENDED,0.2f));
           //create a box having length = l, breadth = b and height = h
           Box box = new Box( (float )l, (float)  b, (float) h, app);

           // vector to translate the item box to the position (x, y, z)
           Vector3f position = new Vector3f((float) x, (float) y, (float) z);
           //creation of a 3D transform group
           Transform3D transform = new Transform3D();
           transform.setTranslation(position);
           tg2.setTransform(transform);
           //add new item box to the transform group
           tg2.addChild(box);   

           return tg2;

         } 
}
```

When running the program I get multiple frames with containers drawn in them but no items

I know that my problem is in the BranchGroup `scene` because I get this error :

```
javax.media.j3d.RestrictedAccessException: Group: only a BranchGroup node may be added
```

because of this line :

```
scene.addChild(Interface.addItem(item[p].getLength(), item[p].getBreadth(), item[p].getBreadth(), x, y, z));
```

I tried fixing the problem with the `scene.detach()` but nothing changed (maybe

I put the detach method in the wrong place, I am not sure)

Does anyone know how to create multiple scenes and in each scene I draw the container and the packed items?

I hope you understood my problem.

I cannot post the full code and all the classes here because it is too complicated.

Thank you.

Comment: you deleted your previous accounts so I dont know if I am even trying to answer this

Comment: Sorry but make an effort to post a SSCCE: http://sscce.org If we have no way to reproduce your problem, we won't be able to help you. You cannot add a TransformGroup into your BranchGroup.

Comment: @gpasch : The Java3D questions in my previous account are different from this one. This is a whole different code. I wrote a new one.

Comment: @gouessej : I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I did to make it work is as follows:

I made the BranchGroup scene1 , the canvas and the universe global variables:

```
private static SimpleUniverse simpleU ;
private static Canvas3D canvas3D;
private static BranchGroup scene1;
```

I created the 3D inteface within the container's class constructor:

```
public ContainerW(final int iD) {

    super();
    cRef = iD;
    this.emptyBreadth = 0;
    this.length = 0.8;
    this.height = 0.6;
    this.breadth = 0.5 - emptyBreadth;
    this.usedVolume = 0;
    volume = length * breadth * height;
    this.packedItems = new ArrayList<ItemsUnit>();


    //----------------------INTERFACE----------------------------

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //create a canvas3D
        canvas3D = new Canvas3D(SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration());
        this.add(canvas3D, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //create a universe
        simpleU = new SimpleUniverse(canvas3D);
        simpleU.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();

        //create a branch group scene 
        scene1 = new BranchGroup();


       //create an appearance for the container
        Appearance app = new Appearance();
        //Create the polygon attributes
        PolygonAttributes polyAttr = new PolygonAttributes();
        //Set them so that the draw mode is polygon line
        polyAttr.setPolygonMode(PolygonAttributes.POLYGON_LINE);
        polyAttr.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);
        //Use these in the appearance
        app.setPolygonAttributes(polyAttr);

        //rotate the view angle 
        Transform3D rotateCube = new Transform3D();
        rotateCube.set(new AxisAngle4d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, Math.PI /4.0));

        //create a transform Group for the container
        TransformGroup tg1 = new TransformGroup(rotateCube);
        tg1.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_READ);

        //create a box: container
        Box container = new Box ( (float) length , (float) breadth, (float)height, app);

        //add the container to the first transform group
        tg1.addChild(container);

        //add the first transform group to the branch group
        scene1.addChild(tg1);

        scene1.setCapability(BranchGroup.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND);

        scene1.compile();

        simpleU.addBranchGraph(scene1);


       Frame frame = new MainFrame(this,800, 800); 


}
```

and with every new item added I make another BranchGroup `scene` and add it to the global BranchGroup `scene1` as follows:

```
            TransformGroup tg2 = new TransformGroup ();
               //set the appearance of the product boxes (transparent) 
               Appearance app = new Appearance(); 
               app.setTransparencyAttributes(new TransparencyAttributes(TransparencyAttributes.BLENDED,0.2f));
               //create a box having length = l, breadth = b and height = h
               Box box = new Box( (float )item[p].getLength(), (float) item[p].getBreadth(), (float) item[p].getHeight(), app);

               // vector to translate the item box to the position (x, y, z)
               Vector3f position = new Vector3f((float) x, (float) y, (float) z);
               //creation of a 3D transform group
               Transform3D transform = new Transform3D();
               transform.setTranslation(position);
               tg2.setTransform(transform);
               //add new item box to the transform group
               tg2.addChild(box);
               tg2.setCapability(Group.ALLOW_CHILDREN_EXTEND);
               BranchGroup scene = new BranchGroup();
               scene.addChild(tg2);
               scene1.addChild(scene);
```

Now, I get both ,container and packed items, in the frame.